# What is the corresponding PHP curl settings for curl -i -k -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d' for posting an xml file

Tags: php, xml, curl

What is the corresponding PHP curl settings for "curl -i -k -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d'"
for posting an xml file to a Server?

Comment: Nice examples below but make sure you use "Content-type:application/xml" instead ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if ($ch = curl_init()) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
       'filename'=>'@/path/to/file'
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: text/xml'
    ));


    $out = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: oops. forgot that post has to be associative, try now

Answer (score 0):

- `-i`: `CURLOPT_HEADER = true`
- `-k`: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false`
- `-H 'Content-type: text/xml'`: `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER = ['Content-type: text/xml']`
- `-d`: `CURLOPT_POST = true`

To set these options, use `curl_setopt_array()`:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CULROPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: text/xml')
));
```